# Циклы и разветвления

Tags: python, python-3.10

Изучаю Python, и тут беда:
Даны натуральные числа n, a1, ..., an. Нужно определить количество членов являющихся квадратами четных чисел.
Я вот на основе одного кода сделал

```
from random import randint

n=int(input('Введите количество членов последовательности: '))
s=[0]*n
for i in range(n):
    s[i]=randint(1,100)
print(s)
ans=0
for i in range(n):
    if  math.pow(i, 2)==0:
        for i in s:
            ans=ans+1
print("Количество членов последовательности являющимися квадратам четных чисел =", ans)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Что вы думаете по вашей задаче? какой код уже написали? покажите. Для этого нажмите [edit] под вашим вопросом

Comment: нужно определить среди n членов сколько из них являются квадратами этих самых членов?

Comment: Zhihar, да, мне нужно именно чтоб в указанной пользователем последовательности чисел считалось количество тех чисел чьи квадраты четные

Comment: Приведите точную формулировку задачи

Comment: откуда вдруг в комментарии вылезло слово "четные"?

Answer (score 1):

```py
import math
array = [] #ваш исходный массив
array_sqrt = [math.pow(i, 2) for i in array]
count = 0
for i in array_sqrt:
    if i in array:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Comment: А где здесь саму последовательность вписывать? У меня просто ноль появляется

Comment: Ну как бы я пробовал, на основе одной из своих работ... Но у меня грубо говоря не получается

Comment: Артем, в своем блоке кода Никита указал вам комментарием, куда нужно вписать последовательность